# python memoization

Tags: python-3.x, memoization

I am new in dynamic programming..
This is a python code for finding shortest combination of numbers that add up to exactly the target sum using memoization.

```
    global memo
    memo={}

    def bestSum(targetSum,arr):
        if targetSum in memo:
            
            return memo[targetSum]
    #Base conditions
            if targetSum==0:
                    return []
            if targetSum<0:
                    return None

            # Branching statments  
            shortestCombination=None
            for i in arr:
                    remainder_combination=bestSum(targetSum-i,arr)
                    if remainder_combination != None:
                            combination=remainder_combination
                            combination.append(i)
                            if shortestCombination ==None or len(shortestCombination)>len(combination):
                                    shortestCombination=combination
            
            memo[targetSum]=shortestCombination
            return shortestCombination



    print(bestSum(10,[1,4,5]))
```

But the output was this

> [4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1]

whereas the correct output is

> [5,5]

if i comment the memoization statements the output will be correct..
This is the python code without memoization for the same problem...

```
    # global memo
    # memo={}

    def bestSum(targetSum,arr):
    #     if targetSum in memo:
            
    #         return memo[targetSum]
    #Base conditions
            if targetSum==0:
                    return []
            if targetSum<0:
                    return None

            # Branching statments  
            shortestCombination=None
            for i in arr:
                    remainder_combination=bestSum(targetSum-i,arr)
                    if remainder_combination != None:
                            combination=remainder_combination
                            combination.append(i)
                            if shortestCombination ==None or len(shortestCombination)>len(combination):
                                    shortestCombination=combination
            
            # memo[targetSum]=shortestCombination
            return shortestCombination



    print(bestSum(10,[1,4,5]))
```

The above code gave me the correct output.

The correct output is also obtained in java script for the same problem with memoization by using object

```
    const bestSum=(targetSum,numbers,memo={})=>{
    if(targetSum in memo) return memo[targetSum];
    if(targetSum===0) return  [];
    if(targetSum<0) return null;

    let shortestCombination =null;

    for (let num of numbers){
        reminderCombination=bestSum(targetSum-num,numbers,memo);
        if(reminderCombination !==null){
            const combination=[...reminderCombination,num]
            if(shortestCombination===null || combination.length< shortestCombination.length){
                shortestCombination=combination
            }
        }
    }

    memo[targetSum]=shortestCombination
    return shortestCombination
};

console.log(bestSum(10,[1,4,5]))
```

Few more examples

```
print(bestSum(7,[3,4,7]))
print(bestSum(20,[1,2,3,4,5,10]))
print(bestSum(3,[3,2,1]))
```

Correct outputs
[7]
[10, 10]
[3]

Wrong outputs when memoization is used
[7]
[10, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 10]
[3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 10, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]
Thank you!

Comment: so you want to store the previously computed values into a list for some faster calculation right? is that what you mean?

Comment: You could and you should try to explain your `Problem description` clearly.  What  do you mean by 'shortest combination` of numbers?

Comment: @GhostOps  Yes, Storing the previously computed values into a list for some faster calculation.

Comment: @Denz then just do the other code (which is other than the memorization code) in a seperate function, which is inside a [cache decorator from functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)

Comment: @DanielHao User can input a number which is known as target sum here and a list a numbers. The function has to  find out minimum possible combination of that numbers that can exactly sum up to the target sum. Repetation of numbers are possible.

Comment: Ohh great..Thank you @GhostOps Is that a new property , that `@cache` ?

Comment: @Denz i have no idea about the property thing, i like to use it to avoid my code do the same function twice with the same data it had been through, did it work? should i put it as an answer?

Comment: Thank you @GhostOps . I didn't try it. I hope that would work, it would be a correct answer. Actually my friend told me a wrong part in my code, I have to use `copy()` method in order to copy a list , without using it we are referencing the list not coping.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use `copy()` method in order to copy a list, without using it we are referencing the list not coping.

```
    memo={}
    def bestSum(targetSum,arr):
            if targetSum in memo:
                    return memo[targetSum]
            if targetSum==0:
                    return []
            if targetSum<0:
                    return None
            shortestCombination=None
            for i in arr:
                    remainder_combination=bestSum(targetSum-i,arr)
                    if remainder_combination != None:
                            combination = remainder_combination.copy()
                            combination.append(i)
                            if shortestCombination ==None or len(shortestCombination)>len(combination):
                                    shortestCombination=combination.copy()
            memo[targetSum]=shortestCombination
            return shortestCombination
    print(bestSum(10,[1,4,5]))
```